# How to change given $variable values being used on echo script depending user choice function

Tags: php, variables

First of all I have some php code checking which user is logged if true in order to give them their respective account values. After that there are some values on a couple of variables that lead to different file links on the database. These variables are used inside a script for a map on an echo output after the variables are set. Conclusion is that I want to implement a language change in the application, but in order to do that the values on the variables will need to change to the respective language ones.

For example: Initially the `$bars` is set to `$row['barsgr']`, what we want is that when the language is selected, the $bars will change to `$row['barseng]`.

I tried using cases but I have no idea how to implement that on the current occasion.

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = '" . $_SESSION['userUid'] . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $bars = $row['barsgr'];
      $food = $row['foodgr']; 
echo "<script>I am a map script that uses the variable $bars to show a layer but want to change the value when another language is picked so I show the translated layer from another column</script>";
?>
```

I expect when a language selector is selected outside the php code, the variables inside the php code to change to their respective language ones.

E.g someone selects english, 
`$bars = $row[barsgr];` changes to `$bars = $row[barseng];`

Comment: how you are using language selector?

Comment: Being done through another php config file. Could write the code down if it helps. It's actually two files. one called config.php and another for each language. The gr.php or eng.php files are the ones that change html stuff like title or <p> . E.g in the eng.php : ```<?php $lang = array (
  "drink" => "Drink",
  "food" => "Food", ?> ``` . But this is actually another file, along with it's config.php file that makes the language change happen.

Comment: To be exact though, the current language changer let's say, only changes some text inside my html. Nothing else. Just stating in order not to confuse.

Comment: how do you save/retrieve which language has been chosen?

Comment: The config file that manages the language has this code. Hope it gives some clues on the solution to the whole thing. `<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
      if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
      $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
      else if ($_GET['lang'] == "gr")
      $_SESSION['lang'] = "gr";
    }

require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
 ?>
 `. As stated, the en.php and gr.php files that I have do the function above in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this could help:

```
<?php

  $lang= $_POST['lang'] // Or maybe $_SESSION['lang'] if you store it there
  if(!isset($lang)) {
    $lang = 'gr';
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = '" . $_SESSION['userUid'] . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $bars = $row['bars'.$lang];
      $food = $row['food'.$lang]; 
echo "<script>I am a map script that uses the variable $bars to show a layer but want to change the value when another language is picked so I show the translated layer from another column</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Will try it out right away. But a question first. At this point: `$bars = row['bars'.$lang]` what is the supposed row in the database be? Something like bars.en or bars.gr ? I don't get it. Sorry but I'm 2-3 months in to php and I'm still missing a lot of information. What I mean is, with your workaround should I make a new column in the database. I guess so. In that case what should the name of the column be ?

Comment: Supposed column in DB shoud be "barsen" or "barsgr", but for example, and to make your DB nicer to the eye, you could use $bars = row['bars_'.$lang] and than your column in DB would be "bars_en" or "bars_gr"

Comment: Getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF).

Comment: Mistake in my example `$language` should be  `$lang`...changed it

Comment: A thousand thank is a little to comment dude. Perfection. You made my day Like A LOT. Thanks again and have a perfect weekend !